# Is there a way to print a Pandas Dataframe like how Pyspark displays Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I would like to print my pandas dataframe with the same style as pyspark table **without converting the pandas dataframe it to a pyspark's one**. Like so:

```py
> print(df.to_string(style='pyspark'))

| Id|groupId|matchId|assists|
+---+-------+-------+-------+
|  0|     24|      0|      0|
|  1| 440875|      1|      1|
|  2| 878242|      2|      0|
```

intead of:

```py
> print(df.to_string())

  Id  groupId  matchId  assists
0 0        24       0         0
1 1    440875       1         1
2 2    878242       2         0
```

Does anybody have a small script that reformats this?

Comment: The [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) package can come pretty close, though I don't see an exact match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DataFrame.to_markdown`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) provides several `table_fmt` options via [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': [0, 1, 2], 
    'groupId': [24, 440875, 878242],
    'matchId': [0, 1, 2],
    'assists': [0, 1, 0]
})
```

Some similar options include:

```
print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt="orgtbl", index=False))

|   Id |   groupId |   matchId |   assists |
|------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
|    0 |        24 |         0 |         0 |
|    1 |    440875 |         1 |         1 |
|    2 |    878242 |         2 |         0 |
```

```
print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt='pretty', index=False))

+----+---------+---------+---------+
| Id | groupId | matchId | assists |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| 0  |   24    |    0    |    0    |
| 1  | 440875  |    1    |    1    |
| 2  | 878242  |    2    |    0    |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

```
print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt='psql', index=False))

+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   Id |   groupId |   matchId |   assists |
|------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
|    0 |        24 |         0 |         0 |
|    1 |    440875 |         1 |         1 |
|    2 |    878242 |         2 |         0 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I neeeded. Thank you King Henry :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2 , 3],
                   'col' : ['a', 'b', 'c']})
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

+----+-----------+-------------+
|    |   id      | col         |
|----+-----------+-------------|
|  0 |    1      | a           |
|  1 |    2      | b           |
|  2 |    3      | c           |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: This is a great plan B, thank you @droebi